# svelte reactive assignment run unexpectedly

Tags: svelte

I have a simple component with two dropdowns where value of first dropdown controls options on the second one.

[image]

[REPL to full code](https://svelte.dev/repl/a212fc155a4546dea954ab92260f9c81?version=3.50.1)

Whenever the first dropdown (Layout) changes, I want the first available option on the second dropdown (Lesson) to be selected. To acheive this, I have this reactive assignment on line 28

```
$ : lessonkey = validLessons[0].id
```

I would expect this line to ONLY execute when `validLessons` changes ? But I find this line executes even when the second (Lesson) dropdown changes resulting in the first option always being selected. Could somebody point out what is the issue with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue seems to be a Svelte bug with reactivity and select bindings. If you look at the generated code, `validLessons` is invalidated when the second select value is changed.

```js
    function select1_change_handler() {
        lessonkey = select_value(this);
        ((($$invalidate(1, lessonkey), $$invalidate(2, validLessons)), $$invalidate(5, layout)), $$invalidate(0, layoutkey));
        (($$invalidate(2, validLessons), $$invalidate(5, layout)), $$invalidate(0, layoutkey));
    }
```

I don't see why this should happen. However, because `validLessons` is invalidated, your `lessonkey` reactive statement is being re-run.

One way to work around this is to make the dependency on `layoutkey` explicit so that we no longer have a dependency on `validLessons`. If the behavior you want is "reset the lesson dropdown when the layout dropdown changes", you can also write the following:

```js
    $ : validLessons = lessons.filter(lesson => layout.script.some(s=> s==lesson.script))
    $ : layout = layouts.find(l => l.id == layoutkey)
    $ : lesson = validLessons.find(l => l.id == lessonkey)
    $: if (layoutkey) setFirstLesson();
    
    function setFirstLesson() {
        lessonkey = validLessons[0].id
    }
```

Now, reactive statement #4 only depends on `layoutkey`, so it will only re-run when `layoutkey` changes (and not `validLessons`). This is because Svelte only looks at values that appear in that statement, and not variables that appear in the function called by that statement (so, `layoutkey` is a dependency, and `validLessons` is not).